# Building Electron app can't find resources files

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have an electron react app (built with create-react-app) which runs fine in development mode, but when I use electron-packager to publish it both the .css and .js files have the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

Looking in the developer tools network tab I can see it is looking for the files at *file:///static/js/main.83d4505c.js* and *file:///static/css/main.00ef8ad8.css* while the file/folder structure is:

- build
- static
- js

  - main.83d4505c.js
- css

  - main.00ef8ad8.css
- App-darwin-x64

  - App (The executable app)
- public
- src
- ...

I use the below code for my main window:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
        ? 'http://localhost:3000'
        : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
);
```

I have tried adding `"homepage": "./",` to the package file as suggested on https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1769 but it doesn't help.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently \"BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
  },
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "directories": {
    "buildResources": "build",
    "app": "build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.5",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "electron": "^19.0.4",
    "electron-builder": "^23.0.3",
    "electron-packager": "^15.5.1",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you publish the package.json please?

Comment: Can you place your `js` and `css` directories within your `src` directory and refer to the files within via relative (vs absolute) paths (in your `.html` file(s))?

Comment: I have similar problem to you and community methods didn't work

Comment: I don't know the real fix, but editing the generated `index.html` file from react-scripts to make the static assets relative fixed it for me.